# How to get the keys of empty elements in an array if the corresponding element in a similar-sized array is a number (without iteration)?

Tags: php, arrays, key, compare

I have two same-sized arrays `$array1` and `$array2`, both with the usual consecutive numerical keys. `$array1` contains numbers, `$array2` contains text. I cannot change this structure to accommodate multi-dimensional arrays or what.

Without going through the whole array, how do I get the keys `i` of the elements in $array2 where

1. `$array1[i]` is a number; BUT
2. `$array2[i]` is empty?

For example:

```
// numbers
$array1 = array(NAN, NAN, 1, 0, 3.5, NAN, 2, 4, 0.5);

// text
$array2 = array(FALSE, FALSE, "abc", "abc", FALSE, FALSE, "text", "abc", FALSE);
```

expected result:

```
// keys of $array2 where $array1[i] is a number and
// $array2[i] is empty/null/false

Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 8
)
```

I've been trying to implement `array_keys()` and `array_udiff()` and other PHP array functions to do this but I just can't.

Help, guys, thanks!

Comment: Please post some more data.
and have you tried this $var as $key => $value

Comment: If you need to check if a value exists for $array2[ i ] you can use the `isset` directive http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: thanks, @ThinkingMonkey. question updated. any thoughts now?

Comment: "Without going through the whole array". Impossible unless you convert to another datastructure. To convert to another datastructure you have to "go through the whole array", though.

Comment: thanks, @chris, what's the fastest/most efficient way to do this, then?

Comment: @AnaBan what was the problem was array_keys giving you? I know you have accepted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will perform in linear O(n) time.

```
$keys = array();
foreach ($array1 as $i => $v1) {
    if (is_numeric($v1) && !$array2[$i])
        $keys[] = $i;
}
```

[is_numeric](http://www.php.net/is_numeric)()  accepts a little more than what most people consider "numbers", but if that's a problem just replace with another function.

I also assumed your definition of "empty" is a value that php would [convert to boolean false](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). Again, adjust as necessary.

Comment: lol, was about to update with my similar but less elegant answer. awesome, dude, thanks! and btw, `is_numeric()` and `false` are spot on.

Answer (score 0):

i'd do something like this:

```
<?php
    $keys = array();
    foreach($array1 as $iterator){
        $key = array_search($iterator,$array1);
        $elem_in_array1 = $array1[$key]; //= $iterator
        $elem_in_array2 = $array2[$key];
        if(is_numeric($elem_in_array1) && emtpy($elem_in_array2)){
            $keys[] = $key;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks @Andreu, i'm so sorry, i should've included that i was trying to avoid going through the whole array. but if there's no other way, i'll definitely give this a spin. any thoughts? thanks man

Answer (score 0):

This will grab the first value in $arr1 that matches $value, as well as the corresponding value in $arr2 at the index of the value found in $arr1.

```
<?php

function array_magic ($value, $arr1, $arr2) {
    $index = array_search($value, $arr1);

    if ($index === false) {
        return false;
    }

    if(!isset($arr2[$index])) {
        $value2 = null;
    } else {
        $value2 = $arr2[$index];
    }

    return array( $value, $value2 );
}
```

Comment: hi @Jonathan, thanks, i'm sorry i just updated the question: i was trying to avoid going through the whole array. that possible?

Comment: I noticed your update and have updated my response in turn. array_search still iterates through the array, but it does so in C so it's faster than a foreach.