# php array lookup time

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures, hash, dictionary

I just thought I would comb through this to find the answer:
http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/

But I couldn't find it. In C++ `<map>` is implemented as a balanced binary search tree with const key values. this is nice, you get `O(log n)` search, insert, delete, etc runtimes. `O(n)` enumeration time.

What I'm wondering is the underlying data structure of PHP arrays. There are a few SO posts on PHP arrays that say "well they do pretty much the same thing, so don't worry about it!". not what I'm after. Is it `O(1)` (hash table) or `O(log n)` (balanced binary tree) lookup? (for example)

If anyone can help me out or point me to the right PHP C source file, that would be awesome (though a little explanation would be good - I'm really bad at C). Or if you just have cool insights about PHP arrays that's good as well - I'm trying to understand the entire underlying data structure.

Comment: [How does array_keys do the search for value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8659224/858515)

`read the comments in the accepted answer.`

Comment: Maybe you will be interested also in this article http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/28/Supercolliding-a-PHP-array.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that
>   associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several
>   different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash
>   table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack,
>   queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees
>   and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

The implementation is in fact some sort of a `HashTable`.

-> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
-> [How is the PHP array implemented on the C level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350361/how-is-the-php-array-implemented-on-the-c-level)

Comment: that's really not the answer I'm looking for. so php decides how it is "treated" at runtime (or bytecode compilation time)? because an ordered map is a balanced binary tree - which by definition can't have an `O(1)` lookup time like a hash table